# Django IllegalMonthError

Tags: django, django-views

I have an url:

```
url(r'^costs/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$', views.day_stats_detail, name='day_stats_detail'),
```

I've created a link to next page, based on:

```
mr = calendar.monthrange(int(year), int(month))

next_year = int(year)
next_month = int(month)
next_day = int(day)+1
if next_day > mr[1]:
    next_day = str(1).zfill(2)
    next_month = str(next_month +1).zfill(2)
if int(next_month) > 12:
    next_month = str(1).zfill(2)
    next_year += 1
another = "/costs/{}/{}/{}/".format(next_year, next_month, next_day)
```

And everything is fine, but I've receveid error when I try skip to the 01.01.2017:

IllegalMonthError at /costs/2017/01/01/

bad month number 0; must be 1-12

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

OMG. Your logic cool :D

Maybe more easy to do some like this?

```
fmt = "%Y/%m/%d"
today = datetime.strptime("/".join((year, month, day)), fmt)
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
another = "".join(("/costs/", tomorrow.strftime("%s/" % fmt)))
```

Comment: Nope:
TypeError at /costs/2016/12/31/

an integer is required (got type str)

Beside of that, I must get number with following zero

Comment: [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>>> import datetime
>>> year = 2016
>>> month = 12
>>> day=31
>>> today = datetime.date(year, month, day)
>>> tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> another = "/costs/{year}/{month}/{day}/".format(year=tomorrow.year,
                                                    month=tomorrow.month,
                                                    day=tomorrow.day)
>>> another
'/costs/2017/1/1/'

Comment: Could you also provide me a informations what should i import? I had a little problems with strtime....